# HTML & CSS: How to style an HR tag to have a title embedded in it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an HR that follows the below model:

```
-----<title>-------------------------------------------------
```

This is a fairly common UI pattern but I'm not finding an example for how to make this work in HTML. Does anyone have any ideas or even pointers to examples? I've been googling it this morning and haven't found what I need so far.

Oh, and additionally I want it for a set of form inputs.

thanks!

Comment: what you might be looking for is fieldset]: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp

Comment: @dnl Only if we're talking about a `form` here. And please, [don't use W3Schools as reference](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: Ah, fieldset/legend worked perfectly. If you put that in an answer I'll accept it and +1 it. Either way great answer and thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<fieldset>
     <legend>title</legend>
</fieldset>
```

You could then apply CSS to these elements to get the desired effect

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a `<fieldset>` tag.

The `<fieldset>` element represents a set of form controls optionally grouped under a common name.

> The name of the group is given by the
>   first legend element that is a child
>   of the fieldset element, if any. The
>   remainder of the descendants form the
>   group.

The `<legend>` element represents a caption for the rest of the contents of the legend element's parent fieldset element.

The `dir` attribute can be used to specify the alignment of the text.

`rtl` for right

```
-------------------------------------------------<title>-----
```

`ltr` for left

```
-----<title>-------------------------------------------------
```

By default it is `ltr`

example:

```
<fieldset dir="rtl">
    <legend>Fieldset Demo</legend>
</fieldset>
```