# How can i draw a line in Android with HTML codes?

Tags: android, html, line

I want to draw a line in Android with HTML codes ? (not in xml codes)

I want to use just one textview for a lot of screens because i don't want to use different layout files.

I tried my HTML code on browser and it worked. But same code is not working in Android.

```
<html>

<h4> BLA BLA BLA <hr color=#A5C940> </h4> 
<font color=#6C6C6C> bla bla bla </font>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `<font>` as it's a deprecated tag.

Comment: Do you mean the web browser in android or actually in an Android app?

Comment: actually in an Android app

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how android is getting this, but the standard line tag voor HTML is

```
<HR />
```

I don't think a header tag is allowed to have a HR-tag in it

Read this topic, it probably helps you: [HTML & CSS: How to style an HR tag to have a title embedded in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193751/html-css-how-to-style-an-hr-tag-to-have-a-title-embedded-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Html.fromHtml()` for the display HTML tag in android. Check [HERE](http://javatechig.com/android/display-html-in-android-textview/).

Good Luck.

Comment: i already used it before i ask. It works for bold and colorize text but when i want to draw a line it isn't working. I think Android doesn't support all HTML codes in application